# Retrieve Random Record/Row from DataBase Table Using LINQ 2 SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have in DB table Called Students We make some thing like lottery to know which students are going to be the winner in some thing like game in a school

```
public static List<Students> GetAll()
{
    List<Students> list = new List<Students>();
    var query = from c in new HsInternetDBDataContext().Students
                orderby c.DateCreated ascending
                select c;
    foreach (DAL.Student dr in query.ToList())
    {
        l.Add(new Quotes(dr));
    }
    return list;
}
```

what i want to do is to retrieve random student from this table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the same question are posted in another blog and i quote the answer when i post it :

```
public static Quotes GetRandomStudents()
{
    HsInternetDBDataContext db = new HsInternetDBDataContext();

    var query = from c in db.Students select c;
    int count = query.Count();
    if (query.Count() > 0)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return new Students(query.ToList()[r.Next(0, count)]);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Students();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps because it works with another one has the same situation

Comment: yes I have sen it but i id not work  and he has the same situation but with different entities :)

Comment: and here is another link for the same case: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/23/returning-random-products-using-linq-to-sql.aspx